# Show Trigger Error on VF Page

Tags: visualforce, controller, error-messages

I have a VF page and custom controller on a custom object related to the Contact object. There is also a trigger on the custom object that prevents duplicate entries.  All works fine, however, when a user enters a duplicate value for the custom object record, they get an Apex error:

```
Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, This Type already exists for this Contact: []
Error is in expression '{!saveType}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page newtype: Class.NewController.saveType: line 36, column 1
```

Is there any way to show this as a more user-friendly message on the resulting VF page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can catch those errors:

```
try {
  insert record;
} catch(Exception e) {
  ApexPages.addMessages(e);
}
```

Or you can manually process them:

```
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(new sObject[] { record }, false);
if(!results[0].isSuccess()) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.ERROR, results[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really trying to catch the error, but more to make it a more user-friendly error. Right now is appear as a typical Apex error because the duplicate checking is done in the trigger. Is there a way to re-format the error or show a more simplified message?

Comment: @J.Neilan Yes, you could make it however you'd like. I typically just use ApexPages.addMessages, but you have full control over your logic, so you can make it look however you want.